# Допустимо ли размещать цикл внутри условия?

Tags: javascript

```
 if (numStr[0] === '-') {
  result = negativeNum(numStr);
} else {
  for (let i = length(numStr) - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    result += numStr[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: А что вас смущает?

Comment: Допустимо. Можете представлять себе условие как блок, который будет выполнен лишь тогда, когда условие верно (или блок `else`, который будет выполнен в обратном случае). Внутри условий вы можете использовать такие же конструкции, как и вне. Более того, вы можете неограниченно вкладывать блоки в другие блоки, создавая условие в условии, цикл в условии в условии, цикл в цикле в условии в условии, ну и так далее.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если обратиться к [спецификации](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-if-statement), конструкция `if` имеет следующий вид

```
if ( Expression ) Statement  else  Statement
```

В свою очередь [Statement](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-Statement) может быть следующими конструкциями:

```
Statement:
    BlockStatement
    VariableStatement
    EmptyStatement
    ExpressionStatement
    IfStatement
    BreakableStatement
    ContinueStatement
    BreakStatement
    ReturnStatement
    WithStatement
    LabelledStatement
    ThrowStatement
    TryStatement
    DebuggerStatement
```

В этом списке интересен [`BreakableStatement`](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-BreakableStatement)

```
BreakableStatement:
    IterationStatement
    SwitchStatement
```

Который в итоге приводит нас [к циклам](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-IterationStatement)

```
IterationStatement:
    ...
    for(LexicalDeclaration Expression; Expression) Statement
    ...
```

Отсюда видно, что размещение цикла внутри любой из ветвей условного оператора вполне допустимо.

Comment: По-моему, это XY-проблема, но ответ [неожиданно хорош](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/016/925/498ed76be651cffb6bb9bac6a9bb75c3.png).