# Всегда ли должен завершить IF ELSEом?

Tags: javascript

Всегда ли должен завершить IF ELSEом ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если обратиться к [спецификации](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-if-statement) конструкция `if` имеет две формы

```
IfStatement[Yield, Await, Return]:
    if ( Expression[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] ) Statement[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return] else Statement[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return]
    if ( Expression[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] ) Statement[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return]
```

Следовательно `else` может как присутствовать, так и отсутствовать.

При этом, в случае присутствия `else` будет связан с ближайшим к нему `if` без `else`.

Answer (score 2):

> Всегда ли должен завершить IF ELSEом ?

Нет, не всегда.

Например есть функция, где нужно вывести число на экран только тогда, когда оно больше 10.
Можно написать так:

```
function showNumber(number) {
    if (number > 10)
        alert(number);
    else
        return;
}
```

Однако это бессмысленно. Достаточно написать так:

```
function showNumber(number) {
    if (number > 10)
        alert(number);        
}
```

---

Другой случай:

```
if (count(params) > 0) {
    someVar = filterData(myData);
    filterMap = params;
} else {
    filterMap  ['name' => null];
}
```

Мы видим, что в любом случае мы задаем значение для переменной `filterMap`. То есть какое-то изначальное значение будет. Проще этот код написать так:

```
filterMap  ['name' => null];

if (count(params) > 0) {
    someVar = filterData(myData);
    filterMap = params;
}
```

---

И таких случаев бесконечное множество, когда `else` добавляет избыточность

Comment: А так можно  закончить else if(){}

Comment: @sergei1980 что? не понял

Comment: @sergei1980, можно, подробнее смотри в ответе: [Допустимо ли размещать цикл внутри условия?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790764/186999)